# How to add markers via GeoJSON to an existing layer, without having to reset it

Tags: maps, mapbox, geojson

I'm using [mapbox](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/api/v2.1.5/l-mapbox-featurelayer/).

I have a layer that contains my markers:

```
 map = L.mapbox.map(id, map_id...)
 map.featureLayer # this is the layer containing all my markers
```

What I want is to add markers to this layer without removing the existing ones. But I don't want to just create a marker via L.mapbox.Marker, I want to add them via GeoJSON, because I want to add custom properties to it.

I tried to create a new featureLayer, add the GeoJSON of my new markers via setGeoJSON, then add this layer to the existing one. If I do that, my custom filter (setFilter) isn't applied to this sub layer.

Another idea would be to create another layer, add the json to it via setGeoJSON, then iterate over its markers and add them to the existing featureLayer. Is that a possibility?

**How can I add markers via GeoJSON to an existing layer?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this, it depends on two functions inherited from `L.LayerGroup` called `removeLayer` & `addLayer`:

```
// Create featurelayer and add it to the map
var featureLayer1 = L.mapbox.featureLayer(mapid).addTo(map);

// Create another featurelayer, don't add it to the map
var featureLayer2 = L.mapbox.featureLayer(mapid);

// Wait until ready
featureLayer2.on('ready', function () {
    // Loop over the layers in the layer
    featureLayer2.eachLayer(function (layer) {
        // Remove them from this layer, this is important because a layer
        // (marker, polygon etc) can't be present in two layers at once
        featureLayer2.removeLayer(layer);
        // Add them to the other layer
        featureLayer1.addLayer(layer);
    }
});
```

Personally i'de call that a quick hack. I'de rather use `L.GeoJSON` which has a `addData` method, which can add features or featurescollections without removing the already added features.

```
// Creates empty GeoJSON layer
var geojson = L.geoJson().addTo(map);

// Creates GeoJSON layer with initial data
var geojson = L.geoJson(geojsonObject).addTo(map);

// Add data afterwards
geojson.addData(geojsonObject);
```

I can't make up from the code where you are getting you initial data, if it's the features from a mapbox map, you could load them like this:

```
// Create a featureLayer which loads your features
var featureLayer = L.mapbox.featureLayer('examples.map-zr0njcqy');

// Create empty geojson layer
var geojsonLayer = L.geoJson().addTo(map); 

// Wait until everything is loaded 
featureLayer.on('ready', function() {
    // Turn layer's features back into geojson
    var features = featureLayer.getGeoJSON();
    // Add features to geojsonLayer
    geojsonLayer.addData(features);
});

// Now you can add more data afterwards
geojsonLayer.addData(moreFeatures);
```

You can also fetch them using a single request with jQuery for instance:

```
$.getJSON('http://a.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/MAPID/features.json?access_token=TOKEN', function (data) {
    geojson.addData(data);
});
```

You can use filtering with `L.GeoJSON` in pretty much the same way:

```
L.geoJSON(data, {
    'filter': function (feature) {
        //return true or false
    }
}).addTo(map);
```

Reference: http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#geojson

Tutorial: http://leafletjs.com/examples/geojson.html

Normally i would create an example on Plunker to demonstrate but they're down today, so i'm unable to create a testcase. Did the code above quickly from memory and can't test it so forgive me if i've made any errors.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time! I used a featureLayer because one is present by default on the map object. But you're right, using a GeoJson layer might be what I'm looking for. I had tried your option where you create a temporary layer, but I had not removed the markers from it! So maybe that's why I was having issues, I'll try it.

Comment: Tried it. With the option where I create a temp layer, I still get the issue where the markers added are not taken into account by the filter present on the existing featureLayer.

Comment: Ok, you would need to apply the same filter on the temporary layer too because using `addLayer` bypasses the filtering. That's why i think all in all that using L.GeoJSON is a better option

Comment: hu ho, another issue it looks like. A GeoJson layer can't set its filter dynamically...

Comment: There's no method to do that but you could do something like `geojsonlayer.options.filter = func` That should work but am unable to test atm edit: that won't refilter the features ofcourse, i need some to ponder on this.

Comment: Ok after some digging through the source of Leaflet's L.GeoJSON and Mapbox's L.mapbox.FeatureLayer i've come to this conclusion: FeatureGroup keeps a copy of the original object so i can use a dynamic filter, drawback is that you can't add data. Leaflet doesn't keep a copy of the original object, so it can't use dynamic filtering but it can add data. Turns out it pretty hard/complex to do both otherwise one of them would have done so. You could work around this with L.GeoJSON by keeping your own copies and just clearing the layer, setting the filter and readding the data.

Comment: I can't really see how it's hard, but you're right, they would probably have done it otherwise. Thanks a lot for looking into this as much as you have :) I'm dealing with a small data set, so it's really fine for now to just reuse .setGeoJson on the feature layer.

Comment: Well hard/complex, i guess it isn't their objective to support that. Mapbox because the featureLayer is actually meant to overlay the features belonging to the actual map, nothing more, so adding extra data is a rare usecase. Leaflet because keeping a copy of all the data that passes through does not preform very well memorywise. I'm just speculating here, but i think something along those lines. You could always extend L.GeoJSON and build it yourself, shouldn't be too hard.

Comment: I see what you mean, but this use case is, I would guess, very common for people building web apps with maps, and I find it weird that Mapbox didn't implement it at some level. Would it maybe be possible to pass extra data to L.Marker and use that in the filter? Last thing, maybe you can shed some light on it for me, is a marker a kind layer too? Seems like adding geojson creates a layer per marker, since we iterate on it with eachLayer. Thanks!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72382/discussion-between-ih8-and-robin).